# Laravel Query Builder Multiple Select And Named Columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I'm new at using Query Builder, today I stuck on Query Builder.I'm trying to do name column also multiple select. Here is what I'm trying to convert query builder :

```
SELECT 
users.name,
users.surname,
users.avatar_path,
users.city_id,
users.district_id,
users.neighboor_id,
cities.name as city_name
FROM users,cities
WHERE users.city_id = cities.id
AND users.name LIKE 'bar%'
```

is there any way without using **DB::raw() ?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [join query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins) here

```
DB::table('users')
     ->select('users.name','users.surname','users.avatar_path','users.city_id','users.district_id','users.neighboor_id','cities.name as city_name')
     ->join('users','users.city_id','=','cities.id')
     ->where('users.name','LIKE',$searchText.'%')   //add here your variable
     ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :) I understood how it work